# Q : Why is my java.awt.event.*; import 'unused' yet I use it in my code?

Tags: java, import

Before you read through, I apologize if this question wastes your time.

It's not necessarily a problem, and my code runs fine in any case, so I don't necessarily need a problem solved. It's just more of a curious question.

In a Java file, I use java.awt.event.ActionListener quite frequently through out the code, yet, I don't have java.awt.event.ActionListener imported, and when I do import it, it tells me the import is unused? Is it that I have it imported in another file that is in the same package? Or is action listener just a generalized import, now? Again. Just curious, no actual problem.

Comment: post the code to check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write in code full class name like java.awt.event.ActionListener, then no class import required.
Try write ActionListener and you'll see, that import is needed.

Answer (score 2):

if you have

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

then I believe the specific import is just getting ignored because your code already imported everything from java.awt.event but you'll have to post some code to get a definitive answer. Your question is a little confusing cause you say java.awt.event.* in the title but then java.awt.event.ActionListener in your description

Comment: I don't have java.awt.event imported in my file though.

Comment: I have `import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` imported, that's it. That's where my confusion is. :P

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can avoid to import a class is whenever you have it in the same package as your own or if you are writing the fully qualified name.

Comment: I have `import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` is all.